# Change column collation in sql server 2008 r2, Turkish letters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, collation

We will change collation of our existing databases and columns. We use two different collation 
Turkish_CI_AS,SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CS_AS and we will use SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

I'm wondering if the Turkish special letters are supported by the new collation? So, will the letters like ç,ı,ğ or ü change into different characters?

Answer (score 1):

Collations are a different thing from character encoding. Changing the collation only changes the comparison rules of how characters sort, **not** how they are represented in the database.  However, the collation of the data is used as a hint by the client drivers to map the **non-unicode** characters into specific code pages, according to the table from [Collation and Code Page Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186356%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

So **if** your columns are of type VARCHAR or CHAR then the data *will* (apparently) change, because the characters formerly in the [CP 1254](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254) will be interpreted as characters in the [CP 850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850). So `ç (\231)` will become `þ (\231)` and so on. Strictly speaking you *can* reinterpret the data in the client to any code page you desire, but practically that is unfeasible and requires a lot of low level (ie. driver) knowledge.

But **if** your columns are NVARCHAR or NCHAR then the encoding does not change, since the characters will be [UCS-2LE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoded  and manipulated as such ([`ç \u00e7`](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) will remain `ç \u00e7`). The only thing that will change will be the comparison and sorting rules (which has impact on the [famous Turkish collation dotted and dotless I/i comparison rules](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html)).